# Can (git svn dcommit) output which SVN commands it would run?

Tags: git, git-svn

I know about `git svn dcommit --dry-run`.  However, due to (rename detection/folder deletion/other complicated issues that I can't conveniently predict), I would like to be able to view a dry run that actually outputs the SVN commands it would run, rather than just telling me which commits it's translating.

Example of desired behavior:

```
$ git svn dcommit --svn-dry-run

Commit 03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451:
svn propset svn:executable "*" script
svn rm something

Commit 7b18d017f89f61cf17d47f92749ea6930a3f1deb:
svn propset svn:mergeinfo /branches/something-else:12345-12346
```